# React + Flux: best practice for calling an action after another action?

Tags: reactjs, action, flux

I have a component, let's call it `List`, that calls an action creator `Action1.getItems()`.
After `Action1.getItems()` has retrieved information from a server, I need to call another action creator: `Action2.getMoreItems()`, which is a totally different action in a different file.

Facts:

1. Both actions creators dispatch an action and change a store.
2. I can't call `Action2.getMoreItems()` inside the `_onChange()` of `List` because it throws an error "`Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch ...`"

Possibilities?

1. Call `Action2.getMoreItems()` inside `Action1.getItems()` after the server returns
2. Add a callback so I will have `Action1.getItems(callback)` and call `Action2.getMoreItems()` inside that callback from `List` component.

I believe this might be a very basic use of Flux but I still can't get my head around on how to get it right, both solutions look ugly to me.

Suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `getMoreItems` dependent on the return value of `getItems`?  If so, you can call the action in the `.then` callback of `getItems`.

If it's not, then you can invoke both calls at the same time and then concat the results of the promises.

So my vote is number 2 in your question.  I don't think it's an ugly solution at all.  You are delegating the responsibility of getting items and more items to your actions.  The component itself is ignorant of that and simply dispatched a request for those items.  How they're built should be transparent to the component.

Comment: Thank you for the response, what you say makes sense indeed. Is it ok to require() action creators from another action creators, then?

Comment: IMO, that is completely fine.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the flux implementations have a method like "waitFor", which lets a store wait for another store to finish.

Assuming you need two execute 2 methods in your store: `GetUser` and `GetPermissions`. The first fetches a user and the latter the permissions, the fetched user has. Obviously, `GetPermissions` needs to wait for the user object to be fetched from the first method.

In this case, you would dispatch an action called `GetUser` and make *both* of your store functions listen to that action. So if you dispatch `GetUser` both store methods are executed.

In alt.js (flux implementation) and in many others, there are methods like `waitFor(store)`, so `GetPermissions` can wait for the UserStore to fetch the user. In alt.js pseudocode this would look like this:

```
// UserStore
function getUser() {
    fetch('api/user').then(this.setState);
}

// PermissionsStore
function getPermissions() {
    this.waitFor(UserStore);
    let user = UserStore.getState().user;
    fetch('api/permission', user).then(this.setState);
}
```

This is, as I said, not working pseudocode, but it shows the concept. If you are interested, the flux implementation alt.js is great. Check it out at [alt.js.org](http://alt.js.org)